# Question about request of fastapi, request post

Tags: python-requests, fastapi

I use fastapi to build my web-server.

I need to know the ip address of client so I follow this guildline https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/

This is my router function

```
from fastapi import Request
...

@router.post("/login")
async def login(id: str, password: str, request: Request):
```

My client do like this

```
import requests
...

response = requests.post(my_url, json={"id": id, "password": password})
```

But client gets this message:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["query","dn"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"},{"loc":["query","password"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

Server gives this message:

```
"POST /jobs/login HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

So I think the Request field is needed or the transmitted data format is wrong..

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to explicitly tell FastAPI that you want to retrieve each parameter from the JSON body if you haven't defined a Pydantic input schema.

```py
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI, APIRouter, Body

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()


@router.post("/login")
async def login(request: Request, id: str = Body(...), password: str = Body(...)):
    print(id, password)
    

app.include_router(router)
```

To define a schema for a login request, create a Pydantic class that inherits from `BaseModel`:

```py
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI, APIRouter, Body
from pydantic import BaseModel


class LoginSchema(BaseModel):
    id: str
    password: str


app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()


@router.post("/login-schema")
async def login(request: Request, login: LoginSchema):
    print(login.id, login.password)


app.include_router(router)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found out what is the issue and why you get 422 Unprocessable Entity **Error**.

```py
async def login(id: str, password: str, request: Request):
```

`id` and `password` are query parameters but you are trying to pass `JSON` data instead of query parameters.

`response = requests.post(my_url, json={"id": id, "password": password})`

If you want this code to work you should pass `id` and `password` as query parameters

```py
import requests

my_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login"
id = "1"
password = "hello"
params = {'id': id, 'password': password}
response = requests.post(my_url, params=params)
```

here is the whole code.
`main.py`

```py
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/login")
async def login(id: str, password: str, request: Request):
    ip = request.client.host
    return {
        "id":id,
        "password": password,
        "host": ip
    }
```

`test.py`

```py
import requests

my_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login"

id = "1"
password = "hello"

params = {'id': id, 'password': password}

response = requests.post(my_url, params=params)
```

Comment: Never use query parameters for username/password fields, as they tend to end up in logs and possibly browser histories.